# Scan solution on build, update text file

Tags: c#

We are using PostSharp aspects to abstract a config file. For example

```
    [Configurable(Default = "MyValue")]
    public static string value { get; set; }
```

Will have its getter/setter overridden by Postsharp to pull from a config file each time it is accessed.

The problem is we have to manually create the config file, which can be tedious on large apps.

What would be the best way to generate this config file at build time? I would need to scan all .CS files in the solution and generate the config file entries based upon what I find.

Comment: why not use the standard .net config file format?

Comment: Sure that would work too, but the problem would still be the same. I want a way to generate the config file entries at build time, rather than make a billable developer manually enter them in. Nonetheless if you are interested hit me up on PC and I can show you what we are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up scanning for an interface IHaveConfigs, extracting the appropriate information using reflection and generating the json file. I would post the code but I no longer have access to it.